# When I send get requests, the response is not understood

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, python-requests, request

when i send get requests the response or outcome is not human understandable ..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrL8L.png)

my code:

```
get_log_head = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="86", "\"Not\\A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="86"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36'
}

get_login = session_request.get("https://www.ex.com", headers=get_log_head)
print(get_login.text)
```

what the solve ?

Comment: Do `print(get_login.content[:256])` and post the output here. Perhaps the first few bytes will give us a clue. You could also try to gzip decode the `get_login.content` as I see you're passing `'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br'` in the request headers.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#gzip.decompress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a human readable response I used this code:

```py
import requests
session_request = requests.session()
get_log_head = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="86", "\"Not\\A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="86"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36'
}

get_login = session_request.get("https://www.panago.com", headers=get_log_head)
print(get_login.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the web server is sending you a `brotli` compressed response, since you set `'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',`

The requests module can natively handle gzip, and deflate, and will automatically be decoded for you [(documented here)](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content) but not Brotli. Try modifying your accept-encoding to
`'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate'`